# Why is a text file doubling in size at each execution of this script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a python script which is meant to delete all special characters and capital letters from a text file, but at each execution of the script, the size of the file I use doubles every time, and when trying to print it, it takes more and more time at each execution, as if python was writing a bunch of "ghost" characters that ends up taking a lot of space (and time), and I can't seem to figure out why.

I tried printing the first character of the "text_string" string to verify the hypothesis of the ghost characters, and as I expected, nothing got printed in the terminal. I think that somehow, my string has some kind of invisible characters, that end up taking an absurd amount of space, but text.truncate() does delete the previously written text, as when removing I tried to remove the text.write line, the file was empty..

Here is the script I wrote :

```
temp_letter_1 = temp_letter_2 = ""
with open("my_text_file.txt", "r+") as text:
    text_string = text.read()

    list_to_delete = ["\n","\"","'","«","»","(",")",".","!","?","","^","&","*","_","`","%","#",",","–"]
    special_characters_to_delete = {"é":"e","è":"e","ê":"e","ë":"e","à":"a","ô":"o","î":"i","û":"u","œ":"oe","/":" ",":":" ",";":" ","-":" ","’":" ","   ":" ","  ":" "}

    for i in list_to_delete:
        text_string = text_string.replace(i,"")

    for i in special_characters_to_delete:
        text_string = text_string.replace(i,special_characters_to_delete[i])

    text_string = text_string.lower()

    text.truncate(0)
    text.write(text_string)
print(text_string)
```

Comment: You probably need to seek back to the start of the file before writing.

Comment: `text.seek(0)` after `text.truncate(0)`

Comment: Nothing to do with your actual problem: You should probably familiarise yourself with str.maketrans and str.translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the full answer :
The problem was caused by the python cursor which was not placed back to the beginning of the file after the `text.truncate(0)` line. It seems that the python cursor gets put at the end of the file right after the `text_string = text.read()` line. Hence, the line `text.seek(0)` can be placed whenever needed in the code between the `text.read()` and the `text.write(text_string)` methods.

Answer (score 1):

The last two lines in your *with* block are:

```
text.truncate(0)
text.write(text_string)
```

They should be:

```
text.seek(0)
text.write(text_string)
text.truncate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to seek back to the start of the file, since in your code, you read to the end of the file.

Simply do `text.seek(0)` after `text.truncate(0)`